# Have to count a character occurrence in Nim string type

Tags: nim-lang

How to count a character occurrence in string in Nim, mainly using its native statements prior go to module ? eg.

```
var
 str = "Hello World"
 c : int

c = numChar( "o", str ) # <- illustration only ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199751) is correct but if you do not want to import any modules you can write your own procedure:

```
proc count_char(value: string = "Hello World", ch: char = 'o'): int =
    var cnt_c: int = 0
    for c in value:
        if c == ch:
            cnt_c += 1
    result = cnt_c

var 
    val: string = "Mother Goose"
    ch: char = 'o'

echo $count_char(val, ch)
```

> PS: Unrelated - Need syntax highlight for [nim-lang](https://nim-lang.org/) on SO.

Comment: I would go with import strutils which is in stdlib, so essentially free. Note that the implementation given is essentially the same as the source of stdlib count (accessible with a single click from documentation): https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/7994556f3804c217035c44b453a3feec64405758/lib/pure/strutils.nim#L2000

Comment: on nim syntax highlighting you can upvote either https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402194/add-support-to-stack-overflow-for-highlighting-nim-code or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355491/add-syntax-highlighting-support-for-nim but unlikely to happen in the near future (keep asking - and answering - nim question on SO everyone...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [count](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#count%2Cstring%2Cchar) function from strutils:

```
import std/strutils

let str = "Hello World"
let count = count(str, 'o')
assert count = 1
```

There’s also a string overload for counting sub strings as well.